# What are the main differences between R data files?

Tags: r, r-faq, rdata, rda

What are the main differences between `.RData`, `.Rda` and `.Rds` files?

- Are there differences in compression, etc.?
- When should each type be used?
- How can one type be converted to another?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Rda is just a short name for RData. You can just save(), load(), attach(), etc. just like you do with RData.

Rds stores a *single* R object. Yet, beyond that simple explanation, there are several differences from a "standard" storage. Probably this [R-manual Link to readRDS() function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) clarifies such distinctions sufficiently.

So, answering your questions:

- The difference is not about the compression, but serialization (See [this page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/serialize.html))
- Like shown in the manual page, you may wanna use it to restore a certain object with a different name, for instance.
- You may readRDS() and save(), or load() and saveRDS() selectively.

Answer (score 185):

In addition to @KenM's answer, another important distinction is that, when loading in a saved object, you can assign the contents of an `Rds` file. Not so for `Rda`

```
> x <- 1:5
> save(x, file="x.Rda")
> saveRDS(x, file="x.Rds")
> rm(x)

## ASSIGN USING readRDS
> new_x1 <- readRDS("x.Rds")
> new_x1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

## 'ASSIGN' USING load -- note the result
> new_x2 <- load("x.Rda")
loading in to  <environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
> new_x2
[1] "x"
# NOTE: `load()` simply returns the name of the objects loaded. Not the values. 
> x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @HarlanNelson tried it. Did exactly what I expect. What's your point?

Comment: The point is `load() simply returns the name of the objects loaded. Not the values` . That's a big different with readRDS, rda's load will change something even you don't want, but if you just want a overwrite, then load rda.