# converting .rda to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have some .rda files that I need to access with Python.
My code looks like this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
df = robjects.r.load("datafile.rda")
df2 = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(df)
```

where *df2* is a pandas dataframe. However, it only contains the header of the `.rda` file! I have searched back and forth. None of the solutions proposed seem to be working.

Does anyone have an idea how to efficiently convert an `.rda` dataframe to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Try saving from R an .rds ([single object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370351/1422451)) file.

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. However, I have no control over le generation of the .rda files, and converting them to .rds before loading them with python will be extremely inefficient. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually not really, simply load the .rda files in an R environment and run the `eapply` or `mget` to save every global environ object into individual rds files.

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for your useful question. I tried the two ways proposed above to handle my problem.
For `feather`, I faced this issue:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Not a Feather V1 or Arrow IPC file
```

For `rpy2`, as mentioned by @Orange: "*pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe does not seem to exist any longer in rpy2 version 3.0.3*" or later.

I searched for another workaround and found `pyreadr` useful for me and maybe for those who are facing the same problems as I am: https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr

**Usage**: https://gist.github.com/LeiG/8094753a6cc7907c716f#gistcomment-2795790

```
pip install pyreadr
```

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('/path/to/file.RData') # also works for Rds, rda

# done! let's see what we got
# result is a dictionary where keys are the name of objects and the values python
# objects
print(result.keys()) # let's check what objects we got
df1 = result["df1"] # extract the pandas data frame for object df1
```

Comment: I tried this on a `.rda` file and got this error: `pyreadr.custom_errors.LibrdataError: The file is compressed using an unsupported compression scheme` -- any workarounds?

Comment: Hi @MarcMaxmeister, is it possible to share the file? Actually, that package still has some limitations: https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr. I converted `rda` files from this repository: https://github.com/clauswilke/dviz.supp/tree/master/data and it worked quite well (41 out of 48 are successfully converted). My converted files were saved as `tsv` format here: https://github.com/nguyenhoa93/data-visualization-practice/tree/master/data/resources.

Comment: The .rda file is too big to share. I think gigabytes. It was a genomics database used by a defunct R library.

Comment: I figured out a fix - I had to install R, then save to feather, and then load `from_feather` in python Pandas.

Comment: Note: If interested in using rpy2 with Arrow, there is this - https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2-arrow

Comment: The solution still works even though pyreadr package is a little dated.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, consider converting the .rda file into individual .rds objects using R's `mget` or `eapply` for building Python dictionary of dataframes.

**RPy2**

```
import os
import pandas as pd

import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri    
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

pandas2ri.activate()

base = importr('base')
base.load("datafile.rda")    
rdf_List = base.mget(base.ls())

# ITERATE THROUGH LIST OF R DFs 
pydf_dict = {}

for i,f in enumerate(base.names(rdf_List)):
    pydf_dict[f] = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(rdf_List[i])

for k,v in pydf_dict.items():
    print(v.head())
```

Comment: Why do you need to write out as rds and load back in? I am new to rpy2 but in your "python combined" code you could seemingly run it as far as the line `dfList = base.mget(base.ls())`. Then use a `for` loop over the elements of `base.names(dfList)` to populate `df_dict` with the command `df_dict[i] = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(robjects.globalenv[i])`. At least, that seemed to work for me...

Comment: You are in fact correct, @Nick. Given the five month old question, answer can be streamlined a bit without saving .rds's to disk. I think I got caught up in the weeds and did not see whole picture. Hindsight is always 20-20 right?

Comment: `pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe` does not seem to exist any longer in rpy2 version 3.0.3.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the new [feather library](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) developed as a language agnostic dataframe to be used in either R or Python.

```
# Install feather
devtools::install_github("wesm/feather/R")

library(feather)
path <- "your_file_path"
write_feather(datafile, path)
```

Then install in python

```
$ pip install feather-format
```

And load in your datafile

```
import feather
path = 'your_file_path'
datafile = feather.read_dataframe(path)
```