# Get the number of rows and columns of a rds file without loading it in R?

Tags: r, file, rds

Is there any way to get information about the number of rows and columns in an rds file in r without loading the file?

Comment: I don't think so, read about data formats in R: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21370132/680068

Comment: I think this is a great question. Not what you are asking but I would suggest saving the data as plain text and compress it. You can always add that info to the header of the file (and read the first few lines only).